# Complete Google Apps domain verification

Tags: google-workspace

My domain name is already registered with Google Apps, but I have not verified my domain name. Now, when I am trying to complete the verification process, I am unable to login to Google Apps. Please help me to complete the domain verification process.

Comment: What error message do you receive?